# What setup do I need to fix in Eclipse to get final jni.so file?

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a cpp JNI file to allow me to do pretty much [this](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5555290835770F77&id=5555290835770F77!202) tutorial in two calls so I can use this SURF Feature Detection in a Google Glass app.  This error/problem that I'm having is not Google Glass related, but I believe Eclipse build environment related.  I'm still relatively new to making projects in Eclipse, much less Android projects in Eclipse, so I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that's just ridiculously obvious and I need it pointed out to me.  My main problem is that my final shared library file from the JNI is not being built, but the inbetween file is and my output from the build isn't indicating any explicit errors.

[image: Eclipse Build Output]

[image: Android Project File Setup]

I know I should be able to build a JNI lib file that I can use in the Java in Android because JNI has been used in Android and I was also trying to follow the tutorials provided by the awesome person who made them [here](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/opencv_nonfree_android_jni_demo) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/wghsite/technical-notes/sift_surf_opencv_android).  These tutorials explain how to side-build the nonfree Opencv libs (the ones that contain SURF and SIFT) and put them in an Android project and how to utilize the libraries in JNI in the Android project.

My JNI code is the code from the very first [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5555290835770F77&id=5555290835770F77!202) split into two functions, one that get called to setup the object keypoint setup that only needs to happen once and the other to get called on every frame in the Activity onCameraFrame() function.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {

    // SURF Vars
    Mat mat_object;
    int minHessian = 500;
    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat des_object;
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_android_glass_surfobjrec_Init_Surf(JNIEnv*,jobject, jlong addr_mat_object);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_android_glass_surfobjrec_Proc_Surf(JNIEnv*,jobject, jlong addr_mat_scene);

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_android_glass_surfobjrec_Init_Surf(JNIEnv*,jobject, jlong addr_mat_object) {

        Mat& mat_obj = *(Mat*) addr_mat_object;

        mat_object = mat_obj;
        //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
        detector.detect( mat_object, kp_object );

        // Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
        extractor.compute(mat_object, kp_object, des_object);

        //Get the corners from the object
        obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
        obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( mat_object.cols, 0 );
        obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( mat_object.cols, mat_object.rows );
        obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, mat_object.rows );
    }


    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_android_glass_surfobjrec_Proc_Surf(JNIEnv*,jobject, jlong addr_mat_scene) {
        // Do all the stuff in the while loop in the oneDrive example
        // EXCEPT, draw the keypoints using DrawKeypoints, don't use DrawMatches

        Mat& mat_outputImg = *(Mat*) addr_mat_scene;
        Mat mat_scene;
        Mat des_scene;
        vector<KeyPoint> kp_scene;
        vector<vector<DMatch> > matches;
        //vector<DMatch> matches;
        vector<DMatch> good_matches;
        vector<Point2f> obj;
        vector<Point2f> scene;
        vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
        double max_dist = 0;
        double min_dist = 100.0;
        Mat H;

        cvtColor(mat_outputImg, mat_scene, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        // Detect and calculate keypoints on scene image
        detector.detect(mat_scene, kp_scene);
        extractor.compute(mat_scene, kp_scene, des_scene);

        matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_scene, matches, 2);

        for(int k = 0; k < min(des_scene.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); k++) { //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
            if((matches[k][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[k][7].distance)) && ((int) matches[k].size()<=2 && (int) matches[k].size()>0)) {
                good_matches.push_back(matches[k][0]);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The only error that I am getting is matches[k][0].distance is saying "Field distance could not be resolved."  I'm getting the same error with matches[k].size() and good_matches.push_back(matches[k][0]) says that matches is an invalid argument, but I've compiled all of this same code and run it fine from a regular CPP project in Eclipse using the code on the onedrive link. And these errors do not appear in the build messages.

And for the ndk-build I've pasted the Application.mk and Android.mk files below.
My Application.mk file is as below:

```
#APP_ABI := armeabi 
APP_ABI += armeabi-v7a # you can do either armeabi or armeabi-v7a, steps are the same.
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
```

My Android.mk file is as below:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libnonfree.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := opencv_java_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libopencv_java.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= /Users/samanthahuston/Development/OpenCV-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := nonfree_jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror -O3 -ffast-math
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := nonfree_prebuilt opencv_java_prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nonfree_jni.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

[image: Include Paths]
[image: Libraries]
[image: Library Paths]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like an eclipse IDE error(Field distance could not be resolved.).  Make sure your project include paths(eclipse project preferences->C/C++ build Settings-> C Includes/C++ Includes ) reference your opencv & jni include paths

Comment: @Samhain I've included screenshots of my Properties under the Build Settings for your perusal.  I think I have everything added that I can.  I even pointed specifically to the jni folder in my project for those custom built nonfree libraries.  And I'm not even sure the errors are the cause of the jni so file not getting built, since the build output doesn't say those "Eclipse" errors are of any concern.  So I'm still confused.